# How to Read the csv file data one by one and put into variable Using Groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, automated-tests

Here i am facing One problem that. i want to read the csv file data and one by one put it into a variable and that variable i want to assign a next  Http Request let say ids.csv file which consisting of  values like this

```
23333
23334
23335
22336
23336
```

I am using Jsr223 PreProcessor code:

```
def csvfile = new File('D:/datas/id/ids.csv')
def lines =csvfile.readLines()
lines.each { String line ->
  vars.put('Id_value', line.toString())
}
```

If it is wrong, how to do this with simple code?

Comment: You are override the value each iteration, how will you get all values in 1 variable?

Comment: here Id_values i want to send it to next http request so on that time it will become empty it will take next iteration

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate JMeter CSV data set which add variables with different suffixes, example in [tutorial](https://hellotestworld.com/2015/12/30/iterating-over-a-csv-file-in-jmeter/):

```
String Filename = vars.get("GETfile");
String fileContents = new File(Filename).getText('UTF-8');
def lines = 0  ;
    fileContents.eachLine { line ->
        lines++;
        vars.put("CSVLine_" + lines, line);
    }
vars.put("GETfileLength",lines.toString()) ;
```

and then loop the variables using ForEach Controller:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a some form of counter to your [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) reference names, your current code will create only one `Id_value` variable with the value of `23336`, you need to amend it like:

```
def csvfile = new File('D:/datas/id/ids.csv')
def lines =csvfile.readLines()
lines.eachWithIndex {line, idx ->
    vars.put('Id_value_' + idx, line)
}
```

And you will get:

```
Id_value_0=23333
Id_value_1=23334
Id_value_2=23335
Id_value_3=22336
Id_value_4=23336
```

More information:

- [Groovy Collection.eachWithIndex()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#eachWithIndex(groovy.lang.Closure))
- [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: i just paste the above code and  the variable is not passing inside the request it is not taking the values inside the Id_value_ but it is only taking ${Id_value_}.

-Http Request
--jsr223 preprocessor